# Invalid effective address (assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86

The following code:

```
mov edx,dword[ecx+(5*ebx)]
```

Gives me an error of "invalid effective address".
As far as I know, it is ok to take the content of (register1+ register2 multiplied by a constant). Why am i getting an error here?
Full code:

```
section .text 
    align 16 
    global main 
main: 
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp    
    pushad          

    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, 2
    mov edx,dword[ecx+(5*ebx)]

    popad           ; Restore registers
    mov esp, ebp    ; Function exit code
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Because it is invalid. Consult an instruction set reference. TL;DR: you can only use scaling factors of `1`,`2`,`4` or `8`.

Comment: It's not a general multiply, it's a shift (so only powers of 2 are allowed).  Use a `lea edx, [ebx + ebx*4]` / `mov edx, [ecx + edx]` to do it in 2 steps.

Comment: @PeterCordes Some assemblers can do a little better than just allowing powers of 2. They will automatically turn `lea edx,[ebx*5]` into `lea edx,[ebx+ebx*4]`. Similarly for `lea edx,[ebx*3]` and `lea edx,[ebx*9]`.